# Сложности в простенькой задачи

Tags: java, строки

В строке нужно заменить все буквы "і" Украинской на буквы "i" английские

```
private String ChangeI (String strChangeLine)
{
    String strChangeResult = "";
    Character charTmp;
    String strTmp="";

    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < strChangeLine.length(); iteration++)
    {
        charTmp= strChangeLine.charAt(iteration);

        strTmp = charTmp.toString();

        String str1 = "i";
        String str2 = "І";

        byte[] strCode1 =  str1.getBytes();
        byte[] strCode2 =  str2.getBytes();

        System.out.println(str1.getBytes());
        System.out.println(str2.getBytes());

        if (strTmp.getBytes() == strCode1) strTmp = "i" ;
        if (strTmp.getBytes() == strCode2) strTmp = "I" ;

        strChangeResult+=strTmp;
    }

    System.out.println(strChangeResult);

    return(strChangeResult);
}
```

написал вот такой метод, но он не работает корректно, подскажите кто каким образом можно отличить английское и кириллическое "i"

Comment: разве `s.replace("і", "i").replace("І", "I");` не помогает?

Comment: Replace заменит все или только первую найденную?

Comment: Все. Это можно посмотреть в Javadoc или в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)) на сайте http://docs.oracle.com/javase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Украинская "i" - `\u0456`
- Латинская "i" - `\u0069`

Comment: мне GetByte вернул почемуто

[B@9304b1
[B@190d11

Какие есть еще ​​методы превращения буквы в код и наоборот?

Comment: потому что `getBytes` возвращает массив *байтов*, а символы юникода не однобайтные. Более того, не понятно, зачем массив сравнивать со строкой.

Чем вас не устраивает `s.replace('\u0456', '\u0069')` ?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вариант с Replace не рассматривал, потому что думал что перемещение касается только первого найденного символа а не всех

Comment: а откуда можна взять коди к большим букавм I?

Comment: Все, я уже нашел - таблица символов в Windows, там есть все коды